# No padding when using overflow: auto

Tags: html, css, firefox, overflow, padding

I can’t get `padding-bottom` to work when I use `overflow-y: auto` on a box. I use Firefox.

```css
#container {
  padding: 3em;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
}

#some_info {
  height: 900px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="some_info"></div>
</div>
```

See the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rwgZu/).

Comment: I see even padding (red) around all edges.

Comment: AHa, maybe it's just Firefox?

Comment: I confirm the problem in FF17

Comment: W3C has to resolve this issue, hopefully they'll choose the behavior of Chrome!
https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/129

Comment: is this issue fixed now? I'm using Windows and Chrome 92.0.4515.159, tried the fiddle and `padding-bottom` works as expected

Comment: I fixed this problem by removing `display: flex` from the parent container.
Not sure why it works, though. `display: grid` works fine. Related [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26888428/display-flex-loses-right-padding-when-overflowing)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

One more solution without extra DIVs.

```
#container:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Working in FF, Chrome, IE8-10.

Comment: Any way to make it work for the right side? In Firefox the horizontal scroll ends when the content is right on the edge of the box, and it ignores extra padding.

Comment: If you wouldn't mind explaining, why the 50px? Is this value specific to the css in the question or could it work for anyone?

Comment: @Booligoosh, the 50px is the size for the "padding". To be more accurate, this should be 3em to reflect the example within the question.

Comment: @isHristov so as I understand it 50px is just a demo value?

Comment: @Booligoosh, that is correct. You can set any value you want and that will be the "padding".

Comment: This works only if you remove the bottom padding from #container, otherwise you get a doubled bottom padding in Chrome.

Comment: This did not work for me. I tried it in the same fiddle provided in the question

Comment: Does not work on FireFox 89.0.2 - still doesn't respect bottom-margin.

Answer (score 19):

I'm late to the party, but I thought it was worth adding a different solution that addresses some of the concerns raised above.

I came here because of exactly the kind of situation that @Philip raised in response to Alexandre Lavoie's solution: I have dynamically generated content inside the container, so I can't just apply styling to a specific div name like `#some_info`.

Happily, there's a simple solution for browsers that support CSS3: instead of applying bottom padding to the container, apply a bottom margin to the last child element inside the container.

```
#container > :last-child {
    margin-bottom: 3em;
}
```

As long as the last child element in the container div is a block-level element, this should do the trick.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/rwgZu/240/

P.S. If Firefox's failure to scroll to the bottom of the padding is indeed a bug (as suggested by @Kyle), it still hasn't been fixed as of Firefox 47.0. Frustrating! Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.17843 exhibits the same behavior.  (Google Chrome, in contrast, shows the bottom padding as expected.)

Comment: Yep, still looks like an open bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=748518

Comment: Does not work on FireFox 89.0.2 - still doesn't respect bottom-margin

Answer (score 9):

The solutions above were not working for my needs, and I think I stumbled on a simple solution.

If your container and overflowing content share the same background color, you can **add a top and bottom border with the color matching the background color**. To create equal padding all around, set the border width equal to the left and right padding of the container.

Link to modified version of OP's fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dennisoneil/rwgZu/508/

A simple example below.

**Note**: Stack Overflow puts the snippet results *into an overflow scroll*, which makes it a little harder to see what's going on. The fiddle may be your best preview option.

```css
#container {
  background: #ccc;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 190px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  border-top: 20px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 20px solid #ccc;
}
#overflowing {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="overflowing">
    This is content<br/>
    This is content<br/>
    This is content<br/>
    This is content<br/>
    This is content<br/>
    This is content<br/>
    This is content<br/>
    This is content<br/>
    This is content<br/>
    This is content<br/>
    This is content<br/>
    This is content<br/>
    This is content<br/>
    This is content<br/>
    This is content<br/>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This kind of works, but it ends up pushing the scrollbar up from the bottom by the amount of the border thickness. So it looks weird.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a possible approach that is working perfectly :

```
#container {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

#some_info {
    height: 900px;
    background: #000;
    border: 3em solid red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Yeah, that's a solution, but let's say that #some_info is dynamic information and not always tagged as #some_info...

Comment: It depends on the content of course, you can also keep an inner div.

Comment: using border with matching background color works best for me

Answer (score 3):

Style the parent div normally and make the inner div do what you want it to do.

Remove `overflow-x` and `overflow` on `#container`, change `height` to `100%`  and add `overflow-y:scroll;` on `#some_info`

```
#container {
    padding: 3em;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: red;
}

#some_info {
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    width:100%;
}
```

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9yuohxuh/

Answer (score 2):

For those who are looking for a simple solution and can change the DOM, put the `overflow` on the outer element and the `padding` on the inner element.

```
.scroll {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.scroll__inner {
    padding: 3em;
}
```

In the example from the original question, it would look like this:

```
#container {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: red;
}

#some_info {
    height: 900px;
    background: #000;
    padding: 3em;
    box-sizing: border-box; /* only needed if wanting padding to not be added to height */
}
```

Note the use of `box-sizing: border-box` here, which is only needed as the OP has a hardcoded height (generally bad practice but could be needed in edge cases), so adding this `border-box` enables the `3em` padding to not increase the height, but pad inside the `900px`.

A final note, I'd advise avoiding ID's for styling, mostly due to their extremely high specificity, [see this post for more info on that](https://csswizardry.com/2011/09/when-using-ids-can-be-a-pain-in-the-class/).

Answer (score 1):

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rwgZu/1/)***

Hi now used to this css

```
#container {
    padding: 3em;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: red;
    padding-bottom:0; // add this line in your css
}

#some_info {
    height: 900px;
    background: #000;
    margin-bottom:3em; // add this line in your css
}
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rwgZu/1/)***

Comment: This works because there's no content. 
When you add content, it overlaps everything in there, even the padding!
Any border, margin or other even container without content is collapsed inside the scrolling div (at least in chrome 43)

Comment: Doesn't work if you use `height: 100vh`, which is my case.

Answer (score 1):

It's not only with bottom padding. Right padding/border/spacing is also ignored (you can't see it in your example because it has no content, and the width is not scrolling)

All the answers above fail in chrome 43, generating up to 3 scrollbars! or if the content overflows #some_info.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/LwujL3ad/

If it worked for you, it's probably because the content was not as wide as the scrolling element, or fixed sized.

**The right solution is:**

Set **#some info** to display:table, and add padding or border to it, not to the scrolling container.

```
#container {
    overflow: scroll;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: red;
    padding-bottom:0;
}

    #some_info {
    display:table;
    border: solid 3em red;
    height: 900px;
    background: #000;
    margin-bottom:3em;
    color: white;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/juh7802x/

The only element that doesn't fail, and respects ANY border and padding you add in there as separator is a TABLE.

I tried, and no matter if it's the next direct child or it's nested many items deep, any non-content styling will NOT expand to wrap the content, and will stay 100% width of the parent. Which is nonsense, because having content BIGGER than the parent is EXACTLY the scenario in which a scrolling div is required!

For a dynamic solution (both the container and the content) set the container of the elements inside the scrolling container to display:table.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [isHristov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22040425/1940710):

```
#container {
    padding: 3em 3em 0 3em; /* padding-bottom: 0 */
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: red;
}

#container:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 3em; /* length you wanted on padding-bottom */
}
```

However, his solution adds extra space in browsers that handle this situation properly.

[Dan Robinson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38177668/1940710) is great too unless you have multiple elements, in #container, that are dynamically shown/hidden. In that case :last-child might target a hidden element and have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add `box-sizing: border-box` to the same element where you applied the `overflow` rule.

Answer (score 0):

I think `@-moz-document url-prefix()` is what you need.

```css
#container {
    padding: 3em;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: red;
}

#some_info {
    height: 900px;
    background: #000;
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  #container > :last-child {
    margin-bottom: 3em;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="some_info"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The top answers did not work in FireFox 89. The only sensible solution I could think of is to use a `div` containing only a non-breaking space and with a fixed height set.

HTML

```
<div className="spacer">&nbsp;</div>
```

CSS

```
.spacer {
    height: 30px;
}
```

This works as it does not utilize margin or padding.

Answer (score 0):

I have just faced this issue, it persists even in Firefox 87, version being released in 2021.

But it is finally fixed very recently. After update to Firefox 93 bottom padding with scroll works normally.