# No bottom padding when using display: grid and scroll

Tags: css, scroll, padding, css-grid

I have a container `div` which has some padding, `display: grid` and `overflow: auto` set. When a child `div`'s height is bigger than the parent's one and a scroll bar appears, it scrolls so that there is no bottom padding.

Here is a [Fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/AlexandrAbakumov/cyb0en8s/6/).

```css
.container {
    background: red;
    display: grid;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 3em;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 300px;
}

.child {
    height: 500px;
    background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

However, if the container is made any other than `display: grid`, the bottom padding is there when scrolled down.

Is this an expected behavior of `display: grid` element? If so, why? What is a proper way of recovering the bottom padding, preferably, with CSS only?

Comment: Same issues [with `display: flex`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26888428/display-flex-loses-right-padding-when-overflowing) and [with mundane `display: block`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722367/bottom-padding-not-working-on-overflow-element-in-non-chrome-browsers) (now fixed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if it's the intended result or a bug but a workaround is to consider an extra element (using pseudo element) to recover the padding:

```css
.container {
    background: red;
    display: grid;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 3em;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 300px;
}

.container:after {
  content:"";
  height:3em;
}

.child {
    height: 500px;
    background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is certainly an option unless someone gives an insight of whether it's happening in accordance with W3C spec or a bug. If former, there could be a way suggested by W3C writers of changing this behavior 'canonically'.

Comment: This is unfortunate that it needs this kind of hack, but thanks for the solution - I can't find anything better right now.

Answer (score 2):

@temani-afif's great answer put me on the right track. But I found it doesn't work when you have columns - the extra `:after` element might get pushed to be the last item in a grid row and not do anything, like this:

```css
.container {
    background: red;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-gap: 1em;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 3em;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 300px;
}

.container:after {
  content:"";
  height:3em;
}

.child {
    height: 500px;
    background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

The first part of my solution was to mark the `:after` element as `grid-column: span 2;` (adjust as needed for your layout)... but then it gave me too much bottom padding because we were seeing the grid-gap setting plus the height of the item added. Final solution was to set the height of the psudo element to the padding value minus the grid-gap value:

```css
.container {
    background: red;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-gap: 1em;
    height: 300px;
    /* remove the bottom padding so it looks normal if your
       overflow: auto does not end up overflowing/scrolling */
    padding: 3em 3em 0;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 300px;
}

.container:after {
    grid-column: span 2;
    height: 2em; /* 3em (desired padding effect) minus 1em (grid-gap setting) */
    content: "";
}

.child {
    height: 500px;
    background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

But watch out - if your grid-gap and container padding are the same - try something like `height: 0.01em` instead of 0, which does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I can no longer reproduce the problem with your snippet, but when I had the problem in my grid layouts a solution (or workaround?) was to set

```
grid-auto-rows: min-content;
```

on the container (or other ways of giving the grid elements a row height of `min-content`, e.g. via `grid-template-rows`).