# CSS-only margin at the end of a horizontally scrolling flex-row container

Tags: html, css, scroll, flexbox

I want to build a horizontal scroller that has margins between each item, and the same margin at the end and the beginning IN the scroller. However, somehow the margin at the end of the container gets eaten up by something.

**Is there some way to have the margin at the end without inserting a 'spacer'-element?**

```css
.scroller {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  
  width: 300px;
}

.item {
  flex: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
  
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.item:first-child {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroller">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: use pseudo element as your spacer element (related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60048710/8620333 for the vertical issue)

Comment: Yay. I already came up with that, unfortunately, my scrolling elements are flex-cols and the after element messes up their layout...

Comment: so better share your *real* use case to get accurate answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
.scroller {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 300px;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.item:first-child {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroller">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think removing flex is an option

Comment: My Question might not imply it, but im not dependent on flex in the scrolling container... I'll accept this as correct

Comment: If you have child element <p> with text inside item div and use white-space: nowrap, it will only have a very long line of text

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can solve this without a pseudo element as a spacer.

All you will need a is a container element:

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.scroller {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.item:first-child {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="scroller">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```