# overflow auto in firefox doesn't show all content that overflows on scroll

Tags: css, firefox, overflow, css-position

I'm currently working on a fixed navigation menu for a client on mobile. I have noticed that in Firefox when you set overflow-y: auto and a max height on a div that it will show the entire div in Chrome and Safari but in Firefox the bottom content is never revealed. I have created a code pen to show what I mean. Try and scroll to the Last item (Literally called "last") in Chrome and you can reach it but try and do the same in Firefox and you can't!

http://codepen.io/acha5066/pen/oXyXZz

```
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow-y: auto;
```

Anyone know what causes this or how to fix it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471910/css-applying-padding-to-box-with-scroll-bottom-padding-doesnt-work/22040425

Answer (score 0):

I think it is due to how firefox and chrome behave to same padding and height values. If you increase or decrease you max-height in any of the browser, you can easily scroll to your last item.