# Firefox padding bottom box-sizing: border-box

Tags: html, css, firefox, padding, border-box

We have a simple parent element with a child element inside. The content of the child element is bigger than the parent, so we want a scrollbar. We want to add some padding to the bottom, but Firefox (60.0.2) seems to ignore this. Is this a bug? In Chrome it appears to be working all right.

```css
#foo{
          width: 200px;
          height: 200px;
        }
        
        #bar{
          box-sizing: border-box;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          padding-top: 20px;
          padding-bottom: 50px;
          overflow: auto;
          background-color: yellow;
        }
```

```html
 <div id="foo">
          <div id="bar">
            test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: This can be helpful for you- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471910/css-applying-padding-to-box-with-scroll-bottom-padding-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add one more div inside the parent element and add the `padding-bottom` to it. Try this code.

CSS

```
#foo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#bar {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.inner {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="foo">
  <div id="bar">
    <div class="inner">
      test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```